# Owl Carousel not working Autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery

Owl Carousel not working  Autoplay

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#owl-demo-main").owlCarousel({
      autoPlay : 1000,
      stopOnHover : false,
       )}
         });
       </script>
```

Comment: please provide some more code or make a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Mine works fine with your script.

Comment: check your console as well if you find any error..

Comment: may be you're using different version, try `autoplay` instead of `autoPlay`

Answer (score 2):

It works if you set **autoplaySpeed** and **autoplayTimeout** to the same value.

```
autoplaySpeed:1000,
autoplayTimeout: 1000
```

you can also try this...

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    items:4,
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplayTimeout:1000,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    autoplaySpeed:5000  
});
```

just so you know this is also a bug that has been reported to **[GitHub](https://github.com/OwlCarousel2/OwlCarousel2/issues/234)**.